# How to use Powershell to convert hex string to bin?

Tags: powershell, converters

I tried to Convert an executable program to hex string.Now I want to use powershell to convert these string to restore a executable program.
I tried this,but it doesn't work.

[image]

my exe-bank.txt like this
[image]

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code or errors. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: `Get-Content` without the `-Raw` switch reads the file as string **array**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, you should read the hex file with switch `-Raw` to get a single multiline string.

Then convert those hex digits to a byte array and output to file.

Try

```
$hex = Get-Content -Path "C:\blah\exe-bank.txt" -Raw

# split the input string by 2-character sequences and prefix '0X' each 2-hex-digit string
# casting the result to [byte[]] then recognizes this hex format directly.
[byte[]]$bytes = ($hex -split '(.{2})' -ne '' -replace '^', '0X')
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\blah\exe-bank.exe", $bytes)
```